# Conceptually, how does one move from three fully connected layers with different kernel sizes to one new fully connected layer?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm attempting to code in Tensorflow the gazecapture model given here:

http://gazecapture.csail.mit.edu/cvpr2016_gazecapture.pdf

Near the end of the model, the eye data, face data, and face grid data have been reduced to three different fully connected layers, of size 1x128, 1x64, and 1x128 respectively. The weights do not appear to be shared but are combined somehow into one final fully connected layer. I am missing the link that joins these together to form the final fully connected layer.

How does this go about? Are there examples of this elsewhere?

The github of the original project is located here if that helps:

https://github.com/CSAILVision/GazeCapture

Thank you! I apologize in advance if this is an elementary mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, so each of the eye, face, and face grid are already reduced down to their own distinct fully connected layers, that makes life easy.  We can use a built in function from Tensorflow to concat like so

```
big_fcl = tf.concat([eye_fcl, face_fcl, face_grid_fcl], 1)
```

*('fcl' stands for 'fully connected layer')*

big_fcl now is 128+64+128 in size.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, they concat outputs from multiple fully connected layers and feed into next one. Following is the code snippet that does concatenation. You can find it in itracker_train_val.prototxt

```
layer {
  name: "concat2"
  bottom: "fc1"
  bottom: "fg_fc2"
  bottom: "fc2_f"
  top: "concat2"
  type: "Concat"
  concat_param {
     axis: 1
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/CSAILVision/GazeCapture/blob/master/models/itracker_train_val.prototxt#L952